# How to retrieve data from MySQL database and place in a HTML Form using Soap Web Services using Java ,

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, soap

I attempted to retrieve user information from the MySQL database, but when I ran my program and searched for the user by name, nothing appeared in the HTML table. I can't figure out what's the issue. Below in my code,

**Web Service Code**

```
 @WebMethod(operationName = "search")
    public List<UserRegister> search(@WebParam(name = "name")String name ) {
      Connection connection = DBUtils.getConnection(); 
 
      List<UserRegister> user = new ArrayList<>();

      UserRegister u=null;

    try {
  
    String searchQuery = "select * from register where name= ?";

    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(searchQuery);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        while (rs.next()) {

            u = new UserRegister();
            
            u.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            u.setBranch(rs.getString("branch"));
            u.setAge(rs.getString("age"));
            u.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
            
            user.add(u);


        }
    }catch(SQLException asd){
        System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
    }
    return user;
}
```

**Java Servlet**

```
@WebServlet("/SearchServlet")
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {

   
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String Name = request.getParameter("name");
        UserRegister userRegister = new UserRegister();
        userRegister.setName(Name);
        searchClass sclass = new searchClass();

        request.setAttribute("name", sclass.search(Name));
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
 
        }
    }
```

**Java Class For Call the Web Service**

```
public class searchClass {
    public List<UserRegister> search( String username) {
    SerachService_Service service=new SerachService_Service();
    SerachService proxy =service.getSerachServicePort();
       
    return (List<UserRegister>) proxy.search(username);
   } 
}
```

**JSp For Search Bar**

```
 <form method="Get"  action="SearchServlet">
<table border="0" width="300" align="center" bgcolor="#CDFFFF">
<tr><td colspan=2 align="center">
<h3>Search Employee</h3></td></tr>
<tr><td ><b>User Name</b></td>
<td>: <input  type="text" name="name">
<tr><td colspan=2 align="center">
<input  type="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
    </body>
```

**JSP Display Data**

```
   <table>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${name}">

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${user.name}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${user.branch}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${user.age}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${user.phone}" />
                                    </td>
                                   
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>

    </body>
```

Comment: Given that there is no exception in any of the server logs for an action the way through to the page, in the JSP page the "user" variable should be typed as some form of the accepted JSP HashMap or such to be iterable. WHERE are the JSP page class imports and the import declaration for the user variable type? Since your data is simple and is always String to pass it to a JSP page why not bring it back separated with commas and use split to array. nb: just a beside point,put in threadsafe=false in the page declarations. You need to declare a JSP bean class in your web.xml import it in the page.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.